# Adding a 'Display all plots' option using ipywidgets and io

Tags: matplotlib, io, ipywidgets, bytesio

I am creating interactive plots using io and ipywidgets. The idea is to be able to select which  'riskdriver' (rd) plot to display. I have the following code which works for each individual plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import io
import base64
from PIL import Image
from ipywidgets import interact

@interact(rd = ['all', 'rd1', 'rd2', 'rd3', 'rd4'])
def display_plot(rd):
  my_results = {}
  for rd in ['rd1', 'rd2', 'rd3', 'rd4']:
    f = io.BytesIO()
    a = np.random.rand(10)
    p = plt.bar(range(len(a)), a)
    plt.savefig(f, format = "png")
    my_results[rd] = f
    plt.close()

  img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(my_results[rd].getvalue()))
  display(img)
```

As you will notice, the code creates an option 'all', however, I am not sure how to adjust the code to actually display all plots when selecting this option. Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use interact (or interactive) to made like this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from ipywidgets import interactive, Output

rds = ['rd1', 'rd2', 'rd3', 'rd4']
all_outs = []
my_results = {}

for rd in rds:
    current_out = Output()
    a = np.random.rand(10)
    p = plt.bar(range(len(a)), a)
    with current_out:
        plt.show()
    
    my_results[rd] = current_out
    all_outs.append(current_out)
    plt.close()

def change_image(value): 
    if value != "all":
        display(my_results[value])
    else:
        display(HBox([my_results[img] for img in rds]))

interactive(change_image, value=["all"]+rds)
```

[image: A picture of four blue graphs in a horizontal line]

But, `ipywidgets` is more powerful than this, so you can use a widget named `Tab` with `Output`, because Tabs only accepts another widgets:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from ipywidgets import Output, Tab, HBox
import numpy as np

rds = ['rd1', 'rd2', 'rd3', 'rd4']
childrens = []

for rd in rds:
    current_out = Output()
    a = np.random.rand(10)
    p = plt.bar(range(len(a)), a)
    with current_out:
        plt.show()
    
    childrens.append(current_out)
    plt.close()

childrens.insert(0, HBox(*[childrens]))
tab = Tab(childrens)
tab.titles = ["all"] + rds
display(tab)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Sergio for the detailed answer. Very helpful.